# JOGL, com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyListener problems

Tags: java, keypress, keylistener, jogl, keyrelease

So, we have an application structure as following:

[image]

in the EC_GUI constructor I initialize the glViewer

```
    private void initGlViewer() {
        /**
         * Viewer.
         */
        glViewer = new GLViewer();
        glViewer.setup();
        centerPanel.add(glViewer.getNewtCanvasAWT());
    }
```

The glViewer implements the GLEventListener and is the following

```
    public GLViewer() {

        GLProfile gLProfile = GLProfile.getDefault();

        GLCapabilities gLCapabilities = new GLCapabilities(gLProfile);

        glWindow = GLWindow.create(gLCapabilities);
        /*
         *  We combine NEWT GLWindow inside existing AWT application (the main JFrame) 
         *  by encapsulating the glWindow inside a NewtCanvasAWT canvas.
         */
        newtCanvasAWT = new NewtCanvasAWT(glWindow);
    }
```

in the glViewer.setup() I add mouse, key and glEvent listeners to the glWindow.

I am using the key and mouse event from the com.jogamp.newt.event.

My keyPressed event in my keyListener starts as:

```
@Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        System.out.println("keyPressed " + ke.getKeyCode());
```

and the keyReleased as well.

Well sometimes I am experiencing inconsistencies regarding the triggering. Let's take as an example when I press the combination ctrl+o to open the fileChooser.

This is as it should be:

```
keyPressed 17
List of pressed inputs
ctrl
keyPressed 79
List of pressed inputs
ctrl
o
keyReleased 17
keyReleased 79
2014.10.09, 10:53:49  [INFORMATION]  Open a project ...
2014.10.09, 10:53:49  [INFORMATION]  Opening file chooser for load.
2014.10.09, 10:53:55  [INFORMATION]  User clicked 'cancel' in file chooser dialog.
```

Here you can see I press ctrl (17), then o (17), they are both released and the fileChooser gets displayed. And then I exit, as you can see it in the last line.

But sometimes this is what I get:

```
keyPressed 17
List of pressed inputs
ctrl
keyPressed 79
List of pressed inputs
ctrl
o
keyReleased 17
2014.10.09, 10:57:34  [INFORMATION]  Open a project ...
2014.10.09, 10:57:34  [INFORMATION]  Opening file chooser for load.
2014.10.09, 10:57:35  [INFORMATION]  User clicked 'cancel' in file chooser dialog.
keyPressed 17
List of pressed inputs
ctrl
keyReleased 79
2014.10.09, 10:57:36  [INFORMATION]  Open a project ...
2014.10.09, 10:57:36  [INFORMATION]  Opening file chooser for load.
2014.10.09, 10:57:38  [INFORMATION]  User clicked 'cancel' in file chooser dialog.
```

I get the ctrl and o keyPressed, but I miss one of the keyReleased, the o in this case. Anyway the fileChooser still gets opened. In the next attempt I press again ctrl+o but this time I miss the o keyPressed. I also miss the ctrl keyReleased. Anyway the fileChooser gets still opened.
But sometimes it doesnt open, for example:

```
keyPressed 17
List of pressed inputs
ctrl
keyPressed 79
List of pressed inputs
ctrl
o
keyReleased 17
2014.10.09, 11:08:57  [INFORMATION]  Open a project ...
2014.10.09, 11:08:57  [INFORMATION]  Opening file chooser for load.
2014.10.09, 11:08:58  [INFORMATION]  User clicked 'cancel' in file chooser dialog.
keyPressed 17
List of pressed inputs
ctrl
keyReleased 79
2014.10.09, 11:08:59  [INFORMATION]  Open a project ...
2014.10.09, 11:08:59  [INFORMATION]  Opening file chooser for load.
2014.10.09, 11:09:02  [INFORMATION]  User clicked 'cancel' in file chooser dialog.
keyReleased 79
keyReleased 17
keyReleased 79
```

I get ctrl-keyPressed, o-keyPressed, ctrl-keyReleased, no o-keyReleased, fileChooser opens, then I close it.
I pressed them again, I get ctrl-keyPressed, no o-keyPressed, o-keyReleased, no ctrl-keyReleased, fileChooser opens, then I close it again.
I press ctrl+o again, I do not get any keyPressed, I just get an o-keyReleased, a ctrl-keyReleased and then another o-keyReleased. FileChooser does not open this time..

Any clue?

Comment: Question already asked here: http://forum.jogamp.org/keyReleased-keyPressed-problem-td4033288.html Please provide a unit test and fill a bug report.

Comment: @gouessej already done

Comment: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1092

Comment: @gouessej exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by checking at every keyPressed/keyReleased event the pressed modifiers by quering each X modifier by KeyEvent.isXDown()

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution for this is on keyReleased() also using

```
if (!ke.isAutoRepeat())
{
 // ... do stuff
}
```

isAutoRepeat() filters out input events automatically sent multiple times by the OS.